# Jquery hover won't show alert

Tags: jquery

I'm using the this code but it doesn't show the alert;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".one").hover( 
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is `.one` dynamically created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a function declaration there. `hover` takes in a function (or two functions) as an argument. Change your code to this :

```
$(".one").hover( function () {
  alert("hello");
}, function() {
  alert("And we're out");
});
```

The first function is for the action which is to happen when you hover over `.one`. The second one is when you hover out of `.one`. You could also do it this way :

```
$(".one").hover(inWeGo, outWeCome);

function inWeGo() {
  alert("hello");
}

function outWeCome() {
  alert("And we're out");
}
```

You could also use `mouseover` and `mouseout` events as well:

```
$(".one").on({
  "mouseover" : inWeGo,
  "mouseout" : outWeCome
});
```

`hover` is the shorthand for these two methods.

More info in docs :

- `hover()` : http://api.jquery.com/hover/
- `mouseover()` : http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
- `mouseout()` : http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: @ hungerpain :   

<a href="main.php" id="link" class="one">Home</a>  

<script type="text/javascript">  

$(".one").hover( function () {  
 alert("hello");  
});  
</script>  

It doesn't work

Comment: @user2309648 could u make a fiddle for this?@ jsfiddle.net

Comment: and @user2309648, u must not have so many elements with the same id

Comment: @ hungerpain what does that do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33014/discussion-between-hungerpain-and-user2309648)

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".one").hover(function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using @krishwader knowledge I used a "false" function to solve the problem with my custom alert modal,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery( "#busca" ).hover(
        function() {
            gvAlert(txtPalabra, txtPalabra);
        },
        function() {return false;});
});
```

Thanks!